# Cannot install any python package pip SSLError

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pip, certificate

I've recently changed my environment path to install vpckg - this has failed so I changed my path back to what is was before, see attached picture with system paths. I don't know if this has generated the issue that I am currently having, but I added the system paths just in case. [image: Image1]

However now when I try to run anything it tells me I have to re-install Numpy. When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\victor.ciulei\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (20.0.2)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I already tried adding

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy`

but I got the same error.

Using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Miniconda did the trick.